# Get the object at top of uiview hierarchy

Tags: objective-c, ipad, view

I have a known location (CGPoint) and I want to query the view (UIView) for the object under it or that contains it, whether its the view itself, or a button inside that, or a label or any other instance

I then want to grab that object, find out it type, and call any methods that happen when its tapped by the user.

I tried calling touchesBegan on the view, but theres no way to create touch events or uievents it seems... correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm thinking there might be a way to do this with hitTest, but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hit test will do it.

If you don't want something returned, turn off userInteractionEnabled

```
        //Send touch down event

        //Now, this is a bit hacky. Theres no public contrustors for UITouch or UIEvent, thus calling touches*: on the view is not possible. Instead, I search the view underneath it (with Hit Test) and call actions on that. 

        //Note. You need to allow for each type of object below, for the scope of the demo, I've allowed for only UIView and UIButton.

        UIView *v = [[self view] hitTest:pointer.frame.origin withEvent:nil]; //origin is top left, point of pointer. 

        NSLog(@"%@", [v class] );

        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
            selectedButton = (UIButton *)v;

        }
        else if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] && [[v backgroundColor] isEqual:[UIColor redColor]]){
            selectedView = v;
            dragLabel.text = @"You are dragging me!";
            dragPoint = pointer.frame.origin; //record this point for later. 

        }
        else {
            NSLog (@"touched but no button underneath it");
        }
```